# finding connected components in scattered x y data

Tags: matlab

I have x y data here is the plot:

[image]

I am trying to find connected components or regions which are closer as one component like shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try k-means clustering: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html

If you know for sure that you will have 2 groups, it will be k = 2.  If you're uncertain in different situations, use evalclusters (https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/evalclusters.html) to decide on the number of groups.  You can also use the distance from the cluster center to filter out points that are too far away.